# acceder a un elemento de mi boton

Tags: javascript, html

Hola quiero acceder a un campo que le asigno a mi div que es parent_id

```
<div id='2'><button id="accion" parent_id="24">añadir</button></div>
```

Tengo la función que llamo cuando hago clik

Y intento recuperarlo con

```
this.parent_id
```

pero me dice que es undefined

Answer (score 1):

si utilizas this para pasar todo el elemento a una function debes y quieres obtener uno de los atributos, debes usar la funcion getAttribute("nombre_del_atributo")

ejemplo:

```
<div id='2'>
  <button id="accion" parent_id="24" onclick="obtenerParentId(this)">añadir</button>
</div>
```

--

```
function obtenerParentId(boton){
    let parent_id = boton.getAttribute("parent_id")
    console.log(parent_id);
}
```